# Error 400 when using Google Translate API

Tags: curl, google-translate

I am currently faced with an error 400 "Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request" when using Google Translate API.

When I directly use the url into the browser, it's OK and return the translation.
cf. https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=[KEY]&target=fr&q=Centrally%20located,%20huge%20room,%20super%20design%20of%20the%20bathroom,%20bathtube&source=en

Here is my PHP code :

```
$base_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?';
$url = $base_url.'key='.$this->api_key.'&target='.$target.'&q='.$text;
if ($source) {
   $url .= '&source='.$source;
}
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$contents = curl_exec($c);
```

Any ideas ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK, found the solution.

I must add :

```
$text = strip_tags($text);
$text = str_replace(' ', '+', $text);
```